# how extensively should the async/await pattern be used?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I came across the following comment on SO:

"Also use of the async await pattern with newer versions of .Net will give the efficiencies closer to that of the event-driven architectures like NodeJS and Nginx"

I inherited a Web API app where basically all methods in all layers leverage the async/await pattern.  The comment above about the performance of async/await is pretty compelling.  Is it proper to implement async/await on all methods of all layers in a Web API app? Are there any scenarios where I should avoid await/async or be careful to not overuse it?

Comment: If you're going to async, you typically want to async all the way.

Comment: You do not need to use `async/await` in apis that doesn't have any I/O.

Comment: "All the methods in all layers" is a huge red flag for me.  I dunno about you, but I've not had the pleasure of an application where "all the methods in all layers" make sense to be async.  Not every process is async friendly (namely serial processes with many steps)..  Nightmares of the ancient JavaScript Christmas Tree pattern are ringing in my head.  Should it be used to that extent?  The 99% answer is no way.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend reading my [intro to async on ASP.NET article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx).

> Is it proper to implement async/await on all methods of all layers in a Web API app?

Yes. In fact, it's imperative. `async` really only works (in terms of providing the benefits you get from `async`) if you use it all the way. So, if your implementation calls another API asynchronously, then that method should be consumed asynchronously, etc., all the way up to your initial controller action.

In particular, you want to avoid sync-over-async antipatterns.

> Are there any scenarios where I should avoid await/async or be careful to not overuse it?

Yes. You should avoid "fake async". This is the antipattern where a developer uses `Task.Run` (or similar) in order to get a task so they can "use async". It often looks like this:

```
int GetId() { ... }
Task<int> GetIdAsync() => Task.Run(() => GetId());
...
var id = await GetIdAsync(); // Look, I'm async! (not really)
```

In this case, the code is hurting your scalability rather than helping it.

Comment: I'd caution the blanket statement "it's imperative ... use it all the way" isn't entirely accurate.  I can certainly create a responsive UI experience regardless of what the backend decides to do.   I like async, but like any other tool it can be overused and comes with a maintenance cost. Some processes are serial and that's ok.  I'd rather keep it that way than try to manage and chain such async tasks using `WhenAll` or the like.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: To clarify, I mean "use it all the way" in the same process, not across the network stack.